# Scheduling Tasks in Python Based on Free Time Intervals

Tags: python

I tried to write a Python program that schedules tasks based on available free time intervals.
The code takes into account a dictionary of free time intervals for each day of the week and a dictionary of tasks with their durations.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import re


def schedule_tasks(tasks, freetime):
    if len(tasks) == 0 or len(freetime) == 0:
        return

    current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%A")
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M %p")

    if current_day not in freetime:
        print("No free time available for the current day.")
        return

    intervals = freetime[current_day]
    intervals = [interval for interval in intervals if interval[1] > current_time]

    if len(intervals) == 0:
        print("No remaining free time for the current day.")
        return

    for task_name, task_time in tasks.items():
        pattern = r'(\d+)h (\d+)m'
        matches = re.match(pattern, task_time)

        try:
            hours = int(matches.group(1))
            minutes = int(matches.group(2))
        except:
            continue

        task_interval = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes)
        scheduled = False

        for interval in intervals:
            start_time = datetime.strptime(interval[0], "%I:%M %p")
            end_time = datetime.strptime(interval[1], "%I:%M %p")
            time_interval = end_time - start_time

            if task_interval <= time_interval:
                end_datetime = start_time + task_interval
                print(f"Task '{task_name}' scheduled from {start_time.strftime('%I:%M %p')} to {end_datetime.strftime('%I:%M %p')}")
                scheduled = True
                break

        if not scheduled:
            print(f"Not enough free time to schedule '{task_name}'.")

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def schedule_tasks(tasks, freetime):
    if len(tasks) == 0 or len(freetime) == 0:
        return

    current_day = datetime.now().strftime("%A")
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M %p")

    if current_day not in freetime:
        print("No free time available for the current day.")
        return

    intervals = freetime[current_day]
    intervals = [interval for interval in intervals if interval[1] > current_time]

    if len(intervals) == 0:
        print("No remaining free time for the current day.")
        return

    for task_name, task_time in tasks.items():
        pattern = r'(\d+)h (\d+)m'
        matches = re.match(pattern, task_time)

        try:
            hours = int(matches.group(1))
            minutes = int(matches.group(2))
        except:
            continue

        task_interval = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes)
        scheduled = False

        for interval in intervals:
            start_time = datetime.strptime(interval[0], "%I:%M %p")
            end_time = datetime.strptime(interval[1], "%I:%M %p")
            time_interval = end_time - start_time

            if task_interval <= time_interval:
                end_datetime = start_time + task_interval
                print(f"Task '{task_name}' scheduled from {start_time.strftime('%I:%M %p')} to {end_datetime.strftime('%I:%M %p')}")
                scheduled = True
                break

        if not scheduled:
            print(f"Not enough free time to schedule '{task_name}'.")


freetime = {
    "Monday": [("08:30 AM", "12:00 PM"), ("02:00 PM", "06:00 PM")],
    "Tuesday": [("09:00 AM", "12:30 PM"), ("03:00 PM", "05:00 PM")],
    "Wednesday": [("08:00 AM", "11:30 AM"), ("01:00 PM", "04:00 PM")]
}

tasks = {
    "Task 1": "1h 20m",
    "Task 2": "20m",
    "Task 3 Part 1": "20m",
    "Task 3 Part 2": "1h",
    "Task 3 Part 3": "40m",
    "Task 3 Part 4": "40m",
    "Task 4": "30m"
}

schedule_tasks(tasks, freetime)
```

The provided tasks should be scheduled like this:

> Task 'Task 1' scheduled from 08:30 AM to 09:50 AM
> Task 'Task 2' scheduled from 09:50 AM to 10:10 AM
> Task 'Task 3 Part 1' scheduled from 10:10 AM to 10:30 AM
> Task 'Task 3 Part 2' scheduled from 01:00 PM to 2:00 PM
> Task 'Task 3 Part 3' scheduled from 03:30 PM to 4:10 PM
> Task 'Task 3 Part 4' scheduled from 03:30 PM to 4:10 PM
> Task 'Task 4' and soo on

But it gives:

> Task 'Task 1' scheduled from 09:00 AM to 10:20 AM

Comment: What did you do to try and determine *why* it produced this undesired output?

Comment: That's the only thing I'm not able to figure out for more than an hour. I changed the logic many times and each times resulted in new response.

Comment: Sounds like the perfect time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Why did you define `schedule_tasks` twice?

Comment: "Sounds like the perfect time to learn how to use a debugger" Sure I will learn that

Comment: "Why did you define schedule_tasks twice?" my bad, i pasted the same func twice here. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem comes with using regex to select your times. The code you wrote here will only select times that contain both hours and minutes sections, for example `1h 20m`, but will not match against times with only one of these, e.g. `1h` or `20m`.

```
for task_name, task_time in tasks.items():
        pattern = r'(\d+)h (\d+)m'
        matches = re.match(pattern, task_time)

        try:
            hours = int(matches.group(1))
            minutes = int(matches.group(2))
        except:
            continue
```

It is also important to note that the reason you haven't found this problem is that you are using a `try ... except` without specifying the type of error you are looking for. This is something that should pretty much never be done, and if you want to catch all exceptions they should be at least printed to the console, otherwise it is very easy to miss important errors.

One way I found to get the hours and minutes without regex is the below code, though this is a bit hacky since it relies so heavily on the formatting of the input, so you might like to find another solution for this.

```
hours, minutes = 0, 0
        if 'h' in task_time:
            hours = int(task_time[:task_time.index('h')])
        if 'm' in task_time and ' ' in task_time:
            minutes = int(task_time[task_time.index(' '):task_time.index('m')])
        elif 'm' in task_time and ' ' not in task_time:
            minutes = int(task_time[:task_time.index('m')])
```

One final thing I noticed was that when creating the intervals list, you are comparing the times as strings. This is not a reliable way to compare times since you are using the AM/PM format. You will need to find a reliable way to compare these times, for example converting them to datetimes using the `datetime.strptime()` function.

`intervals = [interval for interval in intervals if interval[1] > current_time]`

Comment below if you have any questions and I'll do my best to answer them.

Comment: Thank You, Well this doesn't provide the actual solution but paved the way to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure exactly what you were going for, but glad I could help.